# Problema con eclipse - Debian

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, java

sucede que yo uso estoy recientemente probando java, e instalé eclipse en mi equipo, no es de altas prestaciones, decidí instalar el plugin para programar apps de android con eclipse y luego de terminar la instalacion del jdk, al intentar realizar la primera app, el tipico hola mundo me aparece este mensaje en la consola y eclipse se bloquea... [image: Captura]

¿Que debo hacer entonces?
Gracias de antemano por su ayuda.

Comment: si puedes, pega el error en vez de poner imagenes `:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error que te muestra es porque tienes un sistema de 32 bits y estas intentando ejecutar algo de 64... lo mas probable que sea el sdk de android...

---

[**Aqui**](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r23.0.1-linux.zip) puedes bajarlas.

Pero mi recomendacion es que, si estas empezando, trabajes con [**Android Studio**](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html), que es el standard para programar android actualmente y no te encontrarás limitaciones como con Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

**En Eclipse, el plugin para trabajar con Android (ADT) no es soportado. La opción es usar [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) ya que es la IDE oficial.**

En cuanto a tu mensaje de error:

> aapt/24.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Una de las causas puede ser la incompatibilidad con tu Android SDK, posiblemente estas trabajando con Debian en una arquitectura de 32 bits y necesitas de 64 bits, pero hay otro punto importante, el 
**Android SDK Build-tools 24.0.1 requiere Java 8!**

Te sugiero revises que arquitectura tienes en tu sistema operativo, si es de 64 bits entonces cambia todas las referencias dentro de tu `build.gradle` de 24.0.1 a 23.0.1 o 23.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

Como se esta diciendo. Eclipse se esta dejando de usar para programar par Android. Hace bastante tiempo que se utiliza Android Studio que es el recomendado por Google.
Si tu sistema operativo es de 32 bits, tus herramientas tienen que ser de 32 bits. En este caso Eclipse o Android Studio.
En caso que tu sistema sea de 64 bits, es mejor que utilices herramientas de 64 bits, pero podrías utilizar de 32 bits, solo que tendrás que instalar algunos paquetes en Debian. Para no complicarte, si tu sistema es de 32 bits, usa herramientas de 32, caso contrario si es de 64 bits, usa de 64 bits.